# Is there an equivalent to HLint for Erlang?

Tags: debugging, haskell, erlang, lint, hlint

HLint is a Haskell lint tool for making code more idiomatic. Is there something like it for Erlang?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a tool called "Tidier": http://tidier.softlab.ntua.gr/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page, which is based on a simpler module called erl_tidy which is part of the syntax_tools library: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_tidy.html.

Tidier is used via a web interface, letting you choose interactively which changes you want it to perform. It can do some amazing things, and is a great tool for learning how to write idiomatic Erlang.

Comment: The link to Tidier is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Its called [erl_lint](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_lint.html)

Comment: erl_lint is just that part of the compiler which checks for errors and warnings in the Erlang code before it gets compiled down to a more low level representation. It won't tell you how to rewrite your code to make it better.

Answer (score 1):

There's now also [elvis](https://github.com/inaka/elvis). Although it is not specifically a linter, it does check that Erlang code conforms to certain rules which can be configured.